# Link to exact page in Wordpress mobile site by changing url in link

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, url, mobile

I have a Wordpress main site, and a Wordpress mobile site. All the url slugs are exactly the same on both sites, except that the mobile site has `m.` in front. I want to let users switch from an exact page on the main site to the mobile site by clicking on one link:

```
<a href="somescript">Mobile Site /a> -> Clicking on this link brings a user from
```

http://example.com/a-page-1
to
http://m.example.com/a-page-1

For the script in the href, I tried many things but it just didn't work.

```
<?php echo 'm. ' . window.location.href; ?>

href=javascript(var $a=window.location.href;$b='m. '.$a;return $b;)
```

For everything I tried, the `'m.'` always ends up appearing at the END of the url, instead of at the start, like I want it too. I'm not sure if this is a Wordpress problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no `www.` prefix, you can do it with JavaScript this way:

```
href="javascript:window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('//', '//m.');void(0)"
```